# How to get all edittext data from listview

Tags: android, listview

My listview have 19 rows and i need to get all edittext data from listview and store into arraylist.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            int itemCount = mListView.getCount();
            Log.d("count", ""+itemCount);
            final ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++){

                view1 = mListView.getChildAt(i);

                Log.d("Position: ", ""+view1);
                EditText tt = (EditText)view1.findViewById(R.id.etqty);
                value = tt.getText().toString();


                    collection.add(value);
            }

            //int position = contractstoreAdapter.getItem();
            Log.d("number", String.valueOf(collection));

        }
    });
```

Here is my error.

```
09-07 08:09:05.526 8669-8669/com.example.chintatt.cbi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.chintatt.cbi, PID: 8669
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.chintatt.cbi.Fragment_orderstock$1.onClick(Fragment_orderstock.java:107)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: did you get the solution for this issue ? I'm facing the same issue in my  project.

Answer (score 1):

ListView doesn't always contain the data, cause a child view is created every time it comes into display

You must have used some adapter to store the data right? Try to get all the info from there. Not from the ListView but from the adapter in which the data contains.

Hope this will help You

If u can tell how u are storing the data in Adapter it would help me further to tell your answer precisely

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)
```

I believe this should be the loop that you need to implement.

Comment: I need to get all edittext data, not only get visible edittext data

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText tt = (EditText)view1
```

Use above line

```
    EditText tt = (EditText)view1.findViewById(R.id.etqty);
```

Why are you calling findViewById(), whether you get edittext in your view itself

Comment: view1 must be an individual cell in the specified ListVie was far as I see.
How does casting it to an EditText solve the problem?

Comment: You are right but seeing the error log i think that , @khor please confirm if your whole view is edit text or not.

Comment: that no solve my problem. ya i need to get whole edit text in list view.